# get all the naturals less than a number in ascending order

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a quiz app, and the options are storage this way:

```
option1 = 'First option'
option2 = 'Second option'
option3 = 'Third option'
numberOfOptions = 3
```

As some questions will have 4 alternatives, others 2, I'm trying to create a method to dynamically retrieve the number of alternatives available.
For that, I have the `numberOfOptions` variable. Based on this number, I need to get all the natural numbers less than it until 1 (as in the example, [1, 2, 3]), where I need to add to `'option'`. The final result must be:

```
['option1', 'option2', 'option3'];
```

For now, what I did was:

```
void options() {
  int numberOfOptions = 3;
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
   print('option${i + 1}');

 }
}
```

On the output I get `option1, option2, option3`, but I'm stuck trying to return it as a `List`

Comment: I think you need to declare a list `final List<String> options = [];` and then in the for loop add items in this list `options.add('option${i+1}');` Eventually you can return it after for loop with `return options;`.

Comment: Hey @SajadAbdollahi, I was just going to edit the question because I did it and worked. But, I'm getting in output first a list with just ['option1'], then ['option1', 'option2'] and finally ['option1', 'option2', 'option3']. Is there a way to only get the final List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One elegant solution would be to make use of the `List.generate()` constructor and achieve our objective with just one line:

```
List<String>.generate(numberOfOptions, (int index) => 'option${index + 1}');
```

The `List.generate()` constructor takes two arguments:

- length;
- a generator function that has an index variable;

You can read more about it on the [official documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-core/List/List.generate.html).

It can be useful as it's much easier to read and leaner than a for-loop.

---

As outlined by [@jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin), another option would be to use the [`collection-for`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators):

```
List<String> options = [
  for(int i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) 'option${i + 1}'
];
```

Comment: You alternatively could use [collection-`for`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators), which would be even leaner and, IMO, even easier to read.

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks for your writing, I've updated the answer to include your suggested solution.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a list in your options() functions and fill it in the foor loop like so:

```
List<String> options(int numberOfOptions) {
   final List<String> options = [];
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
      print('option${i + 1}');
      options[i] = 'option${i + 1}';
   }
   return options;
}
```